# Fixing thumbnail overflow

Tags: css

I've been trying to get the overflowing text to go to a new line, to no avail.
In the [thumbnails section of my website](http://www.omarayoub.com/index), the thumbnail title is set to "overflow: hidden":

```
.thumb_title a {
    color:#333333;
    line-height:18px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.index .thumb_title a:hover {
    background:none;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.thumb_title {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top:2px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:280px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I've read that if the width of the element is set, it will automatically wrap itself.. but the thumbnail_title is already set to 280px. I changed it to max-width but nothing happened. I've also tried adding "word-wrap: break-word" (CSS3), but there was no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `white-space:nowrap;` That prevents text from going to new lines.

These two selectors have `nowrap` and need it removed: `.thumb_title` and `.thumb_title a`

Fixing this will also change the layout. I recommend this:

```
.index .module {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* remove float: left */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did what you said, but is there something else I need to do? Overflowing text still isn't going to the next line, see the thumbnail with the rockets image (first column, second row).. Full title isn't showing.

Comment: @Omar I removed `nowrap` (see my answer) and the full title displayed. Then I fixed your layout using `inline-block` rather than `float`.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't pay attention to that.
Another silly question: How can I increase the vertical space below each thumbnail? They're too close to each other.

Comment: @Omar padding or margin.

Comment: and where's this "inline-block"?

Comment: damn.. try to forget the last five minutes of your life. apologies and thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

There are few things preventing the wrap to happen.

Here the css changed :

```
.thumb_title a {
    color:#333333;
    line-height:18px;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    /*white-space:nowrap;*/
}

.index .thumb_title a:hover {
    background:none;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.thumb_title {
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    padding-top:2px;
    /*white-space:nowrap;*/
    width:280px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

But, you will have another issue with the floating statement , the next image will move right.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Yoann, I appreciate the clarification :)